# Math operations on products alpha-num serial numbers | Database Design

Tags: mysql, sql, database, serialization, database-design

So in my database, I got the tables

```
Product (prodId,Name,Price)
Box (BoxId,prodId,From,To,Available)
```

'`From`' represents the first serial number. And '`To`' the ending serial.
Calculating '`To`' sub '`From`' gives the quantity of `products`.

A client comes and makes an order of a given product with a given quantity. What I need ,is given the 'From' serial number,I calculate 'From' + Quantity.
If the serial numbers were only sequential integers. This would be easy. But this applies to all types of products with different serial numbers. 
For ex :

```
Box( 1,1,ABC00000C,ABC00099K,100)
```

What I want to achieve is this :

```
SELECT From + 50 FROM BOX
```

How Can i deal with the serial number to get the order ending serial ?

Comment: Try writing in SQL what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Post was updated

Comment: Why is last letter of from and to different? Shouldn't just the number be different? Also, can you give more examples of differente serial numbers you are dealing with?

Comment: That's the problem ,I don't know how different can be serial numbers. Can the same product have different last letter on the serial ? A serial number, does it have only one sequential number ?

Comment: What if you write a procedure that takes the biggest number from serial and add a number to it?

Comment: What i've done so far is to split the serial into two parts. Alphanumeric and integer. But this works only if there is an integer on the right. For ex : ABC00050 becomes : "ABC" / "00050". But what if the serial ends with a letter ? I write another procedure to extract the rightest integer ? Here comes the same question, Can the last letter of the same product be incremented

Comment: Update the function with 3 part case. You can increase letter too, but only up to Z.

Comment: So if a given serial is "AB5C-0005B". What will be the next 10 serials ? increasing the letter first or the number ?

Comment: That should be your choice, how you want to implement increments.
I guess -005C, -005D, -005E,  ..., -005Z, -006A, -006B...

Comment: Products aren't mine. Serials aready exists so i don't have the choice. I have to implement a generic function that gusses the next serials of any product. Or at least ,given "From" and "To". Guess what's inbetween

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To deal with such serial numbers you need either (option 1) a fn(x) calculating a serial number given an integer x, or (option 2) a list of available serial numbers.

Option 1 is easiest to implement, but it requires that the person thinking up the serial number format actually did think of making up a conversion formula to convert an integer into a serial number also. If such a formula exists, all you need to do is determine the integer value for the "from"-value, add 50 to this integer value 'x' and determine the serial number for 'x + 50'.

Option 2 requires that you have a list, or can generate a list of serial numbers, plus those serial numbers must be (somehow) logically ordered. Option 2 then applies one of many ways SQL server provides to get the next 50 rows from this list, starting from the row with value "From" in it. Examples of such methodes are "select top (50) ...", window function "row_number() over (order by ...)", "select ... order by ... offset n rows fetch next 50 rows only" or even a cursor.

Added after comment from Wildfire:

I suggest you create a table holding the serials for option 2. Let me explain this by giving an example: what would you do if one item with serial n + 5 happens to have fallen of the production line and was damaged beyond repair? I.e. this one serial number will never be shipped to a customer. I bet you are not going to ship a box with one less item when this happens, nor are you going to discard 49 undamaged products because the one item is missing. Instead you will probably put all products with serials n to n + 4 and n + 6 to n + 51 in a box, leaving serial n + 5 out. In a perfect world this will of course never happen, but in real life things do go wrong sometimes, so you need to able to cope with -for example- missing serials. So I would really suggest creating a table with all serials available for boxing, and simply have your boxing process read it's next 50 serials from this table.

And option 1 can work, even if the serial itself is non-numerical but can be calculated into a numerical. It's just a little more complicated. That's why I said a formula must exist for the serials for the method to work. Here's an example how you could add 50 to serial "ABC00000C", making "ABC00001Y" the to serial:

```
declare @from varchar(9) = 'ABC00000C';

declare @from_int bigint;

with cteSerialCharacters as (
    -- The set of characters used in a serial.
    -- As an example I've taken all number characters plus
    -- all capital letters from the alphabet excluding any 
    -- of these that are easily misread.
    select '0123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ' as chars
),
cteNumberGenerator as (
    select cast (row_number() over (order by (select null)) as bigint) as n
    from ( select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1
            union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 
            union all select 1 union all select 1
        ) t (xyz)
)
select 
    @from_int = sum(power(s.base, (n - 1)) * (-1 + charindex(substring(reverse(s.serial), n.n, 1), s.characterset)))
from (
        select 
            @from,
            cast(len(ch.chars) as bigint),
            ch.chars
        from cteSerialCharacters ch
    ) s (serial, base, characterset)
    inner join cteNumberGenerator n on (n.n <= len(s.serial));


select @from, @from_int;

declare @to varchar(9);
declare @to_int bigint;


select @to_int = @from_int + 50;


with cteSerialCharacters as (
    -- The set of characters used in a serial.
    -- As an example I've taken all number characters plus
    -- all capital letters from the alphabet excluding any 
    -- of these that are easily misread.
    select '0123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ' as chars
),
cteNumberGenerator as (
    select cast (row_number() over (order by (select null)) as bigint) as n
    from ( select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1
            union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 
            union all select 1 union all select 1
        ) t (xyz)
)
select 
    @to = (
            select 
                substring(s.characterset, 1 + (@to_int / power(s.base, n.n - 1)) % s.base, 1) as [text()]
            from (
                    select 
                        cast(len(ch.chars) as bigint),
                        ch.chars
                    from cteSerialCharacters ch
                ) s (base, characterset)
                cross join cteNumberGenerator n
            order by n.n desc
            for xml path(''), type
        ).value('text()[1]', 'varchar(9)')

select @to, @to_int;
```

Comment: Option 2 can't be done. I don't have a list but two serials : "From" and "To". Option 1 works only the serial is a sequential integer. Like I said in previous post.  if a given serial is "AB5C-0005B". What will be the next 10 serials ?

Comment: @Wildfire: Of course both options are possible and Option 2 is preferable. I'll explain by adding to my answer.

Comment: That's assuming that all chars in the serial can be alphanumeric. If so ,it would be pretty easy to add using base36 methods. So my question is : is there any product serial which has a letter at the end ,but this one can only be specific. For example ,5 serials are : "ABC000A" ,"ABC000B" "ABC001A" "ABC001B" "ABC002A"  ?

Comment: That's not a technical question, that is functional. You really should ask your product owner for proper requirements. Please mark as answer if my answer helped you on the technical details. My code shows an example using which you can include any set of characters, not simply alphanumerics in base36.

Comment: I deal with tech products coming from diverse brands. I don't have a technical problem I can implement my own methods. What I'm seeking is ,wether there's a way to know the next serials of any product. Maybe is there a convention on serials ?

Comment: The serial on my Microsoft keyboard: 5174203242098, on my Samsung monitor: MY22HBXS108331Y. From just these 2 random picks, I think it's safe to say there is no generic system to serial numbers generated by different producers for different products.